# Runtime.getRuntime().exec dalvikvm command in android

Tags: java, android, adb, root, dalvik

I want to execute a .dex file in my android device.And I want an app to trigger this .dex to be executed.

the .dex file is hello.dex,the main class is hello.Hello

Hello.java:

```
package hello;

public class Hello {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}
```

}

So I wrote my app like this:

```
try{

                Process proc=null;
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dalvikvm -cp /data/FileOut/hello.dex hello.Hello");

                proc.waitFor();
                java.io.InputStream is=proc.getInputStream();
                byte b[]=new byte[is.available()];
                is.read(b,0,b.length);
                System.out.println(new String(b));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("Read has Exception", "e:" + e);
            }
        }
```

but there are no any information about the output message or error in the logcat.

logcat:

```
 E/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: created from interp,name=java.lang.ProcessManager
 E/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: calling run(),name=java.lang.ProcessManage
```

then I found the key to solve this is how you 'adb push' the dex file to the phone.

if I use

```
adb root
adb push "D:\Hello.dex" "/sdcard/Test"
```

my app works.

when I only use(adb does not get root permission)

```
adb push "D:\Hello.dex" "/sdcard/Test"
```

my app does not work.

And I found that in both of the cases.
when I use 'll' to see my dex file
it boths shows:

```
-rw-rw-r-- root sdcard_rw 760 ....
```

I'm not really familiar with android security mechanism.How I can modify my code? must my app get root permission?

Comment: ADB runs as a user with different permissions than app code does.  What are the ownership and permissions on the target file?  Does it get odex's stashed somewhere?

Comment: Also worth also investigating if you need to specify the full path of dalvikvm itself

Comment: @ChrisStratton no,I found something else,see the editted question

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to be able to execute files off the external storage, period.  Allowing it would be a huge security risk, since code there can be modified by anyone (but maybe the "should not happen" case of writing them as root defeats that).  The various schemes for installing apps to removable media put them in integrity-checked filesystem images, not as bare uprotected files.  Try storing your file in the private storage of the app which will run it, or else (for testing only) somewhere like /data/local/

Comment: Also note that your attempt to store the file on the external storage is inconsistent with your posted code, which tries to execute something at a (normally nonexistent and uncreatable) path on the internal storage.